# How do I efficiently parse a string in C# to return a similarly-named enum?

Tags: c#, enums

Is there a cleaner way of parsing a string that contains a word to describe it's  `RegistryValueKind`? I'm still learning C# and I don't think I'm fully grasping enums.

```
    private RegistryValueKind ParseValueType(string valueType)
    {
        switch (valueType)
        {
            case "String":
                return RegistryValueKind.String;
            case "Binary":
                return RegistryValueKind.Binary;
            case "DWord":
                return RegistryValueKind.DWord;
            case "ExpandString":
                return RegistryValueKind.ExpandString;
            case "MultiString":
                return RegistryValueKind.MultiString;
            case "QWord":
                return RegistryValueKind.QWord;
            case "Unknown":
                return RegistryValueKind.Unknown;
            default:
                return RegistryValueKind.None;
        }
    }
```

Surely this isn't standard coding procedure?

Comment: Enums are number and can be cast to (int).  So I normally use : switch((int)valueType).  Then put the enumeration in the case statement.

Comment: @jdweng By default, yes. But they can also 'inherit' from `byte`,`sbyte`,`short`,`ushort`,`int`,`unit`,`long` and `ulong`. So it's not the case that all enums can safely cast to `int`.